# Loop to interpolate values

Tags: c++, animation

I have a game, and I want to animate some objects of UI, and I want to use some kind of smooth step in animations. How I can do that, using a for loop, or using the main update code?

E.g. I have this code

```
void CGameClass::Update() {
   // doing game stuff here
}
```

and in this part of code, I want to put the code to do these animations, like, getting the scoreboard from X and take to Y, and I don't want these code to be linear, I want to make a smooth step by these two values.

Edit:: I found a function that make this, but as linear

```
float LinearInterpolate(float v1, float v2, float a)
{
    return  v1*(1.0f - a) + v2*a;
}
```

How turn this code to make this a sine curve ?

Comment: There's not enough context to know what's going on. Have you tried implementing it yourself? If so, show us where you're at. That way, we have more context of what you're trying to do.

Comment: i do not have tryed nothing, because i really dont know how do this. To be more specific, i want to move an object from X to Y, using a non linear increment.

Comment: You use the delta of the time passed since last iteration. Based on that you update your stuff. Then no matter how fast/slow execution is, in the same amount of the time the code will be executed.

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_interpolation we need more details to be able to help

Comment: Trying to be more clear still, look this site https://easings.net/#easeInQuint
I want to make the animation run with this curve

Answer (score 1):

A cubic Bézier function defines a path between a begin point P0 and end point P3, using two control points P1 and P2. In the site you linked, we have:

- P0 = (0, 0)
- P1 = (0.755, 0.05)
- P2 = (0.855, 0.06)
- P3 = (1, 1)

Given a time `t` ([0..1]), evaluating the Bézier will give you a position `x` between `P0` and `P3`.
In your situation, you want to produce a position `p` as follows:

```
point p = X + (Y - X) * CubicBezier(point(0, 0), point(0.755, 0.05), point(0.855, 0.06), point(1, 1), t)
        = X + (Y - X) * (3 * pow(1-t, 2) * t * point(0.755, 0.05) 
            + 3 * pow(t, 2) * (1-t) * point(0.855, 0.06) + pow(t, 3) * point(1, 1)
```

In this code, X and Y are inputs of some magical `point` type that supports addition, subtraction and scalar multiplication. `t` is the time since the start of the animation, according to some scale. (for example it might be `(now - start) / 5` for an animation that takes 5 seconds)

As you can see, P = X if t = 0, and P = Y if t = 1. It is your responsibility to make sure `t` is in the range [0..1].